# Do I have to install Android SDK in order to develop Android apps?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm newest in Java Programming, I've already downloaded Elicpse IDE, do I need also the Android SDK Studio?

Comment: ِwill you develop android? if yes, it's better download and install Android Studio but  if you would develop just java download eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK and Android Studio are two different things.
Yes, you must install the SDK if you pretend developing Android apps in Eclipse or Android Studio. That's written in the install instructions.

Comment: Hi Alfarid, okay I've got it, so I should use as an IDE Android Studio or Eclipse?

Comment: Both are bad but Android Studio is the less bad.

Answer (score 0):

Google stopped support Eclipse for Android long time ago. If you are new to Android development, Android studio would be more than enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot Hui, good to know Eclipse is an old tool, so you suggest me to start from scratch Android development use SDK?

Comment: @Swarejg https://developer.android.com/studio/ , it is pretty straight forward. And I think it comes with Android SDK. And try Kotlin instead of Java!